# error in mysql query - for retriving data using date

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

i want a count for a specific month's data from my table tbl_itunes_report.
table structure is

```
id  int pimary key
provider_country   varchar(50)
title   varchar(50)
product_type_identifier varchar(50)
begin_date varchar(50)
```

This is my query

```
 SELECT 
 title,
 sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(begin_date)= '05' THEN 1 ELSE 0) as june
   FROM
 tbl_itunes_report
   WHERE
 `product_type_identifier` = '1T'
 group by title
```

but this query does'nt worked for me. there is an error showing that

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as june FROM tbl_itunes_report WHERE `product_type_identifier` = '1T' group' at line 3
```

if any one can help me, please.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the END keyword at the end in CASE statement

```
SELECT 
 title,
 sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(begin_date)= '05' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as june
   FROM
 tbl_itunes_report
   WHERE
 `product_type_identifier` = '1T'
 group by title
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `END`. Replace

```
sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(begin_date)= '05' THEN 1 ELSE 0) as june
```

with

```
sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(begin_date)= '05' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as june
```